# Deployment of ASP.NET application to Heliohost

Tags: .net, asp.net

Greetings,

I am developing an ASP.NET application (ASP.NET 2.0) using VS 2008 and i want to put it in Heliohost.org. I am searching the web for tutorials on how to do this, but it is not clear to me what's the best method. I was wondering if you guys can guide me through this process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should ask heliohost.org how to do this, since they're using Mono. Note that this is not a programming question as per the FAQ, it's a localized issue with a specific hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a site in VS than VS will upload it. Debugging will not work and you've no ASp.NET WMAT. but all aspx page will work properly with an FTP account.